# Why does it say column ambiguously defined?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, ora-00918

```
select a.id_progdi, a.nama_progdi, avg(b.ipk)  
from tb_ipk b 
join tb_mahasiswa c on b.nim = c.nim 
join tb_progdi a on c.id_progdi = a.id_progdi  
group by id_progdi
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: the error is  ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 7 Column: 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your group by, you should add the table alias because you have the same column name in several tables  and the db engine need to know at which you want to refer

```
    select a.id_progdi, a.nama_progdi, avg(b.ipk)  
    from tb_ipk b
    join  tb_mahasiswa c  on b.nim = c.nim 
    join tb_progdi a on c.id_progdi = a.id_progdi  
    group by a.id_progdi, a.nama_progdi
```

Answer (score 3):

you have multiple `id_progdi` so probably it doesn't know which one to refer to in the `group by`. Change it to `group by a.id_progdi`

Comment: still error now show ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 20

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have id_progdi in multiple tables use table alias for it in your group by.